# How do I insert Images on an Acumatica Email Template

Tags: email, templates, erp, acumatica

How do I insert Images on an Acumatica Email Template.  I would like to create a custom header and signature of the email.  I tried the following options, and both of them did not work:

1. Tried to get access to Branch Logo option but those objects could
   not be found because screen selection seems to be different.
2. Tried to insert an  tag on the template but this also did
   not work.

Answer (score 0):

First you should copy your image into the clipboard, then paste it into the email template. It work good for me!